# Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone not showing correct Design View

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, design-view

For some reason Visual Studio is showing me this weird, ugly skeleton design view when I try building Mango apps instead of the regular fully detailed view I used to get with the old 7.0 apps.

Any idea what setting I need to change to revert back to the old view?  I've spent forever searching for the right option but can't find it anywhere.

Here's what my design view currently looks like:
[image: Skeleton Design View]

Thanks,
Zain

Comment: do you have any errors on your view?

Comment: Nope, this screenshot is from a brand new project, untouched

Comment: @parioscreations have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK?

Comment: If it helps, it seems that this display is only showed when you are using Windows Phone OS 7.1. I recommend that, until a solution is found, that you use Windows Phone 7.0 if you are having the sam problems

Comment: just out of curiosity, does it look right when you open in Blend?  Also, does the app look and work correctly when you run it in the emulator or on a device? This is a really strange problem...

Comment: Might be worth loading another instance of VS2010 and attaching to the first instance and seeing if you get any clues from there.

Comment: I tried reinstalling VS but that didn't fix the issue.  However I just tried opening VS a few days ago (after a couple month siesta) and a new WP7.1 project loads just fine. Weird

Comment: Still doesn't load fine for me. And being a newbie, I don't know how to open a project in Blend. Even if I could, I would still like to alter the GUI on the screen than in Blend.

Comment: And yes, the display is fine when I run it.

Comment: Holy cow. I just opened Blend. Wow....
ANYWAYS
It does seem that it shows the project fine in Blend. Well, hopefully someone responds with a good answer.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, I just realized that I'd installed VS Ultimate on my machine.  That must have fixed whatever was broken. Guess it didn't fix itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problems few weeks ago. Normally an uninstallation would not really help. I guess you also have installed the Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1. So to solve your problem, uninstall all of your Visual Studio and Windows Phone Related Products, normally these are:

- Visual Studio 2010 (or Express)
- Visual Sudio 2010 SP1
- Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh

After uninstallation install all products in the following order:

1) Visual Studio 2010 (or Express)
2) Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh

and after (1) and (2) install and apply the Visual Studio 2010 - Service Pack 1.

Thre problem is, that if you install the SP1 before the Game Studio, there are some missing links and files which are not patched and this leads to the missfunctionality of the Windows Phone Designer.

I hope, i was able to help you :)

Comment: Trying out your theory. Will tell you what happens. Visual Studio 11 Beta is huge!

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much!!!! This deserves to be the top answer, you have solved my problem! I have my good, 'ol view again! Thank you!

Comment: fine, that i was able to help you ;)